# Смена класса у двух блоков одним нажатием

Tags: javascript

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#button-one').click(function () {
  $('#div-one').toggleClass('div-left-close').toggleClass('div-left-open');
  $('#button-one').toggleClass('button-one-bg-close').toggleClass('button-one-bg-open');
 });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#button-two').click(function () {
  $('#div-two').toggleClass('div-right-close').toggleClass('div-right-open');
 });
});
```

```css
#button-one, #button-two {
 display: block;
 width: 20px;
 height: 55px;
}
#button-two {
 color: #fff;
}
 .button-one-bg-close {
 background: #ff0000;
}
.button-one-bg-open {
 background: #ff0;
}
#div-one, #div-two {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 250px;
 background:  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.88);
 margin-top: 50px;
}
.div-left-close {
 left: -250px;
 -webkit-transition: left 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: left 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: left 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: left 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.div-left-open {
 left: 0px;
 -webkit-transition: left 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: left 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: left 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: left 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.div-right-close {
 right: -250px;
 -webkit-transition: right 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: right 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: right 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: right 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.div-right-open {
 right: 0px;
 -webkit-transition: right 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: right 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: right 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: right 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="button-one" class="button-one-bg-close" href="#"></a>

<div id="div-one" class="div-left-close">
 <a id="button-two" href="#">LINK</a>
 Other content
</div>

<div id="div-two" class="div-right-close">
 Other content
</div>
```

Вот полный код. Необходимо, чтобы если оба блока открыты (видны) и нажимается первая кнопка, то закрывались оба блока, а не только первый.

Comment: Не понятен код и ситуация в целом. Покажите лучше ваш HTML и уточните, как должно работать. Я могу точно сказать, что ваш код нужно написать по-другому, а не просто поправить. А как надо написать - не понятно, без html-кода. Вы все усложнили с кодами и кучей классов. Все нужно делать проще.

Comment: В идеале - сделайте код сниппетом. Так ответ за несколько минут уже получите.

Comment: @ИванПшеницын нечего показывать как бы. попробую пояснить что нужно.

Comment: нужно не пояснить, а, как минимум, увидеть html-код. Непонятна структура. И вообще я перечитал 10 раз и так до конца не понял что и когда открывается и что и когда закрывается и сколько там вообще блоков.

Comment: @ИванПшеницын 
Есть два блока и две кнопки. Одна кнопка находится в меню - нажимаешь и появляется первый блок. Внутри первого блока кнопка от второго блока. При нажатии второй кнопки - открывается второй блок. При повторном нажатии они закрываются. Но нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии первой кнопки закрывались оба блока (если второй в открытом состоянии).

Каким образом я открываю/закрываю - блоки с position fixed и left и right -250px (это ширина окна). При клике на кнопку меняется класс у которого left и right = 0px

Comment: Почему вы не можете код добавить сюда? Вы предлагаете мне написать с нуля вам меню и всю эту логику? При том, что у вас уже есть своя логика, которую вы, вероятно, не сильно хотите отправлять в мусорку. Простите, некогда. Поправить ваш код или добавить в него немного нового функционала - другое дело.

Comment: @ИванПшеницын я тут впервые и пока плохо понимаю, как добавить сюда правильным образом код, но вроде получилось. В первом сообщении. Вот, не знаю, что вы хотели увидеть, js код был изначально показан в полном объёме, только блоки и классы дописал.

Comment: ну не знаю, что вы плохо понимаете, добавили отлично и все вдруг стало понятно) так гораздо лучше, спасибо. сейчас разберемся.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конкретно ответ на вопрос состоял из одной строчки. Мне этого показалось мало и я пошел дальше: немного оптимизировал классовую структуру и избавился от некоторого лишнего js после этого.

Зачем давать элементу два класса для открытия и закрытия, если можно обойтись одним: когда он есть - элемент открыт, когда нет - стили по-умолчанию, элемент закрыт.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    var $divOne = $('#div-one');
    var $divTwo = $('#div-two');

    $('#button-one').click(function () {
        $divOne.toggleClass('open');
        $divTwo.removeClass('open');
        $('#button-one').toggleClass('button-one-bg-close button-one-bg-open');
    });

    $('#button-two').click(function () {
        $divTwo.toggleClass('open');
    });
});
```

```css
#button-one, #button-two {
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 55px;
}
#button-two {
    color: #fff;
}
.button-one-bg-close {
    background: #ff0000;
}
.button-one-bg-open {
    background: #ff0;
}
.block {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 250px;
    background:  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.88);
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.block-left{
    left: -250px;
    -webkit-transition: left 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: left 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: left 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: left 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.block-right{
    right: -250px;
    -webkit-transition: right 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: right 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: right 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: right 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.block-left.open{
    left: 0;
}
.block-right.open{
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="button-one" class="button-one-bg-close" href="#"></a>

<div id="div-one" class="block block-left">
 <a id="button-two" href="#">LINK</a>
 Other content
</div>

<div id="div-two" class="block block-right">
 Other content
</div>
```

Comment: `toggleClass` может принимать список классов разделенных пробелом, и в принципе можно убрать проверку `if($divTwo.hasClass('open'))`

Comment: @Grundy действительно. спасибо.

Comment: @ИванПшеницын большое спасибо)
Grundy, благодарю за правку, убрал эту строку)